# ActiveAdmin duplicates nested forms and delete checkbox doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, nested-forms

The form works to add items to the Model but items are not deleting! Worse, any update duplicates all of the nested forms (1x2=2, then the next update makes 4 for each, etc.)

**app/admin/project.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do

  permit_params  :title, :description, :git_url, :demo_url, :version, :lastpublished, :firstpublished,
   project_features_attributes: [:project_id, :description, :_destroy => true],
   project_mentions_attributes: [:project_id, :title, :url, :published, :_destroy => true]

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs
    f.buttons
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Project Details" do
      f.inputs :title
      f.inputs :description
      f.inputs :git_url, :default => "http://github.com/"
      f.inputs :demo_url
      f.inputs :version
      f.inputs :firstpublished
      f.inputs :lastpublished      
      f.inputs do
        f.has_many :project_features,
         :allow_destroy => true,
         :heading => 'Features' do |cf|
              cf.input :description
        end
      end
      f.inputs do
        f.has_many :project_mentions,
         :allow_destroy => true,
         :heading => 'Mentions' do |cf|
              cf.input :title 
              cf.input :url
              cf.input :published
        end
      end

    end


    f.actions
  end
end
```

**app/models/project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_features, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_features,
     :reject_if => lambda{ |a| a[:description.blank?] },
     :allow_destroy => true

    has_many :project_mentions, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_mentions,
     :reject_if => lambda{ |a| a[:title.blank?] },
     :allow_destroy => true

    has_many :blogs

end
```

**app/models/project_feature.rb**

```
class ProjectFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project

end
```

**app/models/project_feature.rb**

```
class ProjectMention < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `:_destroy` instead of `:_destroy => true` in permit_params block.

Duplication: <strike>Delete the content of your public folder. In development mode you don't have to precompile the assets.</strike>

**Update:** you have to permit the id of the related record:

```
project_features_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :description, :_destroy],
project_mentions_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :title, :url, :published, :_destroy]
```

Comment: changing _destroy didn't work.
Also, I don't understand your comment about deleting the public/(404|422|500).html files - what does that to do with ActiveAdmin duplicating the values in my nested forms when performing an update?

Comment: Sorry, I thought, you precompiled your assets. In that case a new 'assets' forlder is created in public folder and the has_many form appears twice in development mode.

Comment: adding the :id fields to the _attributes did the trick, thank you!